# 2 divs overlaying eachother can't hover on both

Tags: html, hover, geometry

Is there any way to hover on both triangles? 
This is what I mean : http://www.free-creations.nl/help 
As you can see I made a border around the triangles.
The triangles are overlaying eachother.
Is it possible to fix this?

```
<div id="galleryp1">
<div class="triangles" id="r1afb1">
    <img src="images/triangle5.png" usemap="#Map"/onclick="img1Big()" border="0">
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
      <area shape="poly" coords="3,262,153,3,301,256,294,263,8,263" href="#"     
onclick="img1Big()" alt="tri1p1" />
    </map>
</div>
<div class="triangles" id="r1afb2">
    <img src="images/triangle2.png" usemap="#Map2" border="0"/>
    <map name="Map2" id="Map2">
      <area shape="poly" coords="153,256,4,4,303,5,162,257" href="#" alt="tri2p1" />
</map>
</div>
<div class="triangles" id="r1afb3">
    <img src="images/triangle5.png"/>
</div>
</div>

</div>


.triangles
{
width:307px;
height:267px;
float:left;
} 

#galleryp1
{
position:relative;
width:1054px;
height:267px;
margin:auto;
top:222px;
}
#r1afb1
{
position: absolute;
left: -1px;
border: #000 thin solid;
}
#r1afb2
{
position:absolute;
left:187px;
border:green thin solid;
}

#r1afb3
{
position:absolute;
left:374px;
border:thin solid red;
}
```

Comment: use z-index attribute

Comment: Can you please post your html/css code ?

Comment: Z-index won't help here. You could make it work, but it'll take some CSS transform trickery so that the elements don't actually overlap. See http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2v2wM for some ideas.

Comment: It's not clear from that demo how the slider is intended to function, but you could also possibly use an SVG image map. See http://demosthenes.info/blog/696/Using-SVG-as-an-Alternative-To-Imagemaps and my implementation of that technique at http://www.atomiclearning.com/highed/campus-wide.